# driver.close() doesn't close the current tab in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a selenium webautomation program for tradingview. It all stays in one tab but when I open a new tab/link which it than switches to and which I than want to close after that, it closes the original tab. It looks like this:

```
for i in range(1, 1001):
input_ = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[x]/td[1]/div/div[2]/a' 
list_input_ = list(input_) 
list_input_[44] = str(i)  
input_ = ''.join(list_input_)
stock = driver.find_element_by_xpath(input_) 
stock.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.close() 
print(input_)
if i > 9:
    break
```

The stock = driver.find_element_by_xpath(input_) and stock.click() opens the new tab/link to the left. But than driver.close() closes the tab I was previously in. I want it close the tab that it just opened and that I'm currently in. Which it supposed to do. It also seems like that none of the selenium commands work on this newly opened tab and only work on the original tab.

The copied element of the link it opens looks like this:`<a class="tv-screener__symbol apply-common-tooltip" href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-STAF/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">STAF</a>`

Did I do something wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls check out my solution and let me know whether it helped u.

Comment: yeah sorry for not responding, it helped but the problem was that it already was in that current handle, so I had to switch from 0 to 1 and than use driver.close(), like this: driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.close(). Thanks for helping!

Comment: Okay...Did my solution help u?

Comment: Yes it helped. I just had to think a little harder haha (:

Comment: Lol...If my answer has helped you, pls upvote my answer and accept it as the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you haven't switched focus to the new tab that you have opened. To switch focus to the newly opened tab, use this line:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

This line switches the focus to the 2nd tab that is open your browser. Then, you can perform the operations that you want in this tab. Then if you want to close this tab, then just use:

```
driver.close()
```

This would close the 2nd tab (the tab that is currently in focus).